# Change ordering of fields in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I want to have an online article in my bibliography but cannot change the way it is displayed. My `.bib` file contains many entries but for this working example, I will only use:

```
@online{european_commission_NGEU, 
    title={EU Budget policy brief: The EU as an issuer : the NextGenerationEU transformation},
    url={https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/accacfb6-0966-11ed-b11c-01aa75ed71a1/language-en/format-PDF},
    author={{European Commission}},
    publisher={Publications Office of the European Union},
    year={2022},
    month={Jul}}
```

With my current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear,sorting=nymdt, maxbibnames=99,autolang=hyphen,alldates=long,dateabbrev=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\textit{#1}} %since i want my title cursive
%to correctly sort
\DeclareSortingTemplate{nymdt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}}
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}}
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{00}  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}}
}


\begin{document}

Text \cite{european_commission_NGEU}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get the output:

> European Commission (July 2022). EU Budget policy brief: The EU as an issuer : the NextGenerationEU transformation. url: https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/accacfb6-0966-11ed-b11c-01aa75ed71a1/language-en/format-PDF.

What I would want:

> European Commission (2022). EU Budget policy brief: The EU as an issuer : the NextGenerationEU transformation. url: https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/accacfb6-0966-11ed-b11c-01aa75ed71a1/language-en/format-PDF. July, 2022.

I looked around for an easy way to achieve that but couldn't find a neat solution. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Does the date have to come after the URL or would it also be OK to have the date before the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't insist on having the date come after the URL and could also accept it coming in before the URL (as is common for all other entry types), you only need to adjust the `mergedate` settings to `basic` and need to set `labeldate=year,` (which is the default, but is overridden by the `alldates=long,`). You may want to check out the other `mergedate` values as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  sorting=nymdt,
  maxbibnames=99,
  autolang=hyphen,
  mergedate=basic,
  alldates=long,
  labeldate=year,
  dateabbrev=false,
  doi=false,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
%to correctly sort
\DeclareSortingTemplate{nymdt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}}
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}}
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{00}  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}}
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@online{european_commission_NGEU, 
    title={EU Budget policy brief: The EU as an issuer : the NextGenerationEU transformation},
    url={https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/accacfb6-0966-11ed-b11c-01aa75ed71a1/language-en/format-PDF},
    author={{European Commission}},
    publisher={Publications Office of the European Union},
    date={2022-07},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Text \cite{european_commission_NGEU}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: European Commission (2022). EU Budget policy brief: The EU as an issuer : the NextGenerationEU transformation. July 2022. url: https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/accacfb6-0966-11ed-b11c-01aa75ed71a1/language-en/format-PDF.]

If you need the date after the URL, it's probably easiest to change the driver with `xpatch`. Add the following to above MWE after you've loaded `biblatex`

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\usebibmacro{date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}
  {\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {}{}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the issue and the additional remark on the order change is also very helpful!